# How to set "CURLOPT_USERPWD" field of libcurl in NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, authentication

I am trying to access a web service using NSURConnection, but i am not sure how to send password there because the example code given in php is setting CURLOPT_USERPWD field of libcurl, and there seems to be no such field in NSURLConnection/NSURLReqest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the username and password, and concat them together with a colon.  Take the resulting string and Base64 encode it.  Take the Base64 encoded string, and prepend "Basic " (with the space).  Now take that string (`Basic [Base64 encoded value]`) and set it as the "Authorization" header for your request.

Alternatively, if you're using the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods, you can implement one of them with something like:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
  NSURLCredential * credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
  [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

(warning: untested, typed in a browser.  *caveat implementor*)

Comment: You mean this way: [request setValue:pwd forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];